# iterate through files ('for file in...) and also include sub directories?

Tags: sed

I am using sed to do a bunch of changes to files.
I think the question is relevant for any operation that want to iterate through files that match a pattern and include subdirectories both in the original file search recursion AND (i.e. creating them to replicate the structure) in the file creation output

I initially get the files with

```
mkdir -p _seded
for file in *_spec.rb
do
  cat $file
  ... a bunch of seds
  > _seded $file
end
```

How can I get the files plus *subdirectories* of files that match the pattern?

For instance if I have

```
spec/ex1
spec/ex2_spec.rb
spec/subs/subex1
spec/subs/subex1_spec.rb
spec/subs/subex2/aaa
spec/subs/subex3/s3_spec.rb
spec/subs/subex4/s4.rb
spec/subs/subex4/bbb
```

then I should get:

```
_seded/ex2_spec.rb
_seded/subs/subex1_spec.rb
_seded/subs/subex3/s3_spec.rb
```

Note: directories subex2 and subex4 should **not** be created as they would be empty.

I tried:

```
mkdir -p _seded
find . -name '*_spec.rb' | xargs cat |
  sed -e '[/pattern/replace code]' > _seded/$file
```

but got errors like:

```
$ ./convert_should_to_expect.sh 
./convert_should_to_expect.sh: line 5: _seded/: Is a directory
xargs: cat: terminated by signal 13
now doing its !!!
sed: couldn't edit _seded/: not a regular file
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `_seded/' for reading (Is a directory)
mv: `_seded/tmp' and `_seded/tmp' are the same file
sed: couldn't edit _seded/: not a regular file
sed: couldn't edit _seded/: not a regular file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
cd spec
find . -type f -name '*_spec.rb' | while read file; do
    mkdir -p ../_seded/"${file%/*}"
    cat "$file" | sed ... > ../_seded/"$file"
done
```

`${file%/*}` will cut off the filename portion of `$file`, so that it can be used in making the output directory in the `mkdir command`

Comment: Looking good.  What about the final `>` - will that 'preserve' the directory structure for the _seded output files?  Also where is $file now being defined (I also got stuck on that).

Comment: The `while read file` will fill the variable `file` with an output line from the find command, looping over the lines. As the output of find contains the path, the filename after `>` will contain that path too. You could put an echo in front of the commands inside the while loop and adjust the quoting to see what happens.

Comment: Yup, that's good.  Only change for me was to remove the `../`'s but that's my preference for file location.  Otherwise looks great.  Thanks!

Comment: OK, I added in the ../ that you showed eventually as it creates a parallel structure so that any requires are at the 'same point' in the directory tree.

Answer (score 2):

This is untested code!  The idea here is to give you the logic I think you should follow.  This does not include subdirectories, but at least it won't create a lot of empty files like your sample code and it has some syntax correction.

The for loop can be improved with something like a grep or a find statement to include subdirs, but it would take me some time to figure that out.  Maybe somebody knows off the top of their head?

```
mkdir -p _seded
TMPFILE=/var/tmp/sedtmp$$$    # Someone can help me with the syntax for a unique file here. 
for file in *_spec.rb
do
  cat $file
  ... a bunch of seds >> $TMPFILE    # Each with this addition after it.
  COUNT=`wc -l $TMPFILE`
  if [ COUNT -gt 0 ]
  then                   
     cp $TMPFILE _seded/$file   
  fi
  > $TMPFILE
done
rm $TMPFILE
```

Comment: +1 I used Michael's approach but thanks for this approach too!